# How to send logs to blob storage after setting up Azure app service log?

Tags: azure, logging, azure-blob-storage

I have followed the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs) and this is my code

```
 public class omeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<omeController> _logger;

        public omeController(ILogger<omeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            
            _logger.LogError("This is error logging in Index");
            
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Welcome to Privacy");
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Error occured");
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
```

In my code, I have purposefully omitted 'H' from 'HomeController', while after publishing it I am receiving the error page on chorome still no log is being entered in my blob storage even after configuring the setting. I have uploaded the screenshot of my [App Service Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOJKa.png)
and [Log folder inside Blob storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hB3sX.png).

I am currently working on .Net 6 and my Program.cs looks like this

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

//This single line of code below is added my me
builder.Logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please  [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

We have tried the same on our environment with `.net6` application and can able to see the logs in Log Stream and stored in blob storage as well.

- Created ASP.NET core application and published to Azure .
  [image]
- Enabled the below settings for logs and to store in blob in our Application.
  [image]
- After sometime we will be able to see the logs in our Container as below:

[image]

NOTE: Please make sure that after enabled we have the following configuration in Azure App service.

```
DIAGNOSTICS_AZUREBLOBCONTAINERSASURL
```

[image]

For more information please refer this BLOG:- [***Configuring Logging in Azure App Services***](https://ardalis.com/configuring-logging-in-azure-app-services/)