# Save App service log into Azure Blob Storage, using Block blobs

Tags: c#, azure, logging, azure-blob-storage

How to save our application logs informarion to Azure Storage blob container as .csv (Block blobs type).

My application developed in Asp.Net core 6.0

Comment: Could you please refer this [SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71153825/how-to-send-logs-to-blob-storage-after-setting-up-azure-app-service-log)

Answer (score -1):

Please check by using the `BlobStream` if it helps to resolve the issue:

```cs
 _container.CreateIfNotExist();

  CloudBlob inputBlob = _container.GetBlobReference(outputBlobUri);
  CloudBlob outputBlob = _container.GetBlobReference(inputBlobUri);

  using (BlobStream input = inputBlob.OpenRead())
  using (BlobStream output = outputBlob.OpenWrite())
  {
    ProcessImage(input, output);

 output.Commit();
 outputBlob.Properties.ContentType = "csv";
 outputBlob.SetProperties();

 AppRepository<Post> postRepository = new AppRepository<Post>();
 Post post = postRepository.Find(partitionKey, rowkey);

 post.PostImage = outputBlobUri;
 post.State = true;
 postRepository.Update(post);
 postRepository.SubmitChange();

 _queue.DeleteMessage(message);
}
```